# Recreating a Rails database when using PostreSQL App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresapp

I'm really new to PostrgreSQL, and I've run into an issue I don't really know how to solve.

I'm currently using the PostreSQL 10 app for OSX; and I'm trying to recreate a Rails app database using `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate`. I get the following error:

```
PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "app_development" is being accessed by other users
```

This other session is the Postgres app keeping a connection open: if I run `ps -ef | grep postgres`, I get

```
502 38332     1   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.15 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin/postgres -D /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-10 -p 5432
502 38334 38332   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.01 postgres: checkpointer process       
502 38335 38332   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.07 postgres: writer process       
502 38336 38332   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.02 postgres: wal writer process       
502 38337 38332   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.04 postgres: autovacuum launcher process       
502 38338 38332   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.17 postgres: stats collector process       
502 38339 38332   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.01 postgres: bgworker: logical replication launcher       
502 38342 38332   0  2:57PM ??         0:00.21 postgres: user app_development [local] idle    
502 38661 38432   0  3:06PM ttys004    0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn postgres
```

I can't just stop the Postgres app and then run the `rails db:drop` command, because then I get the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How can I actually recreate my database? Thanks in advance

Comment: try it  `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: @MayurShah Sorry, forgot to specify I'm on OSX

Comment: Then Try `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: @MayurShah Worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart it `brew services restart postgresql`